# Override field type definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, type-level-computation

I am trying to define a state machine using TypeScript and providing some checks at typelevel.

To do so, I need to keep the configuration not only at value level but also a type-level, to be able to do raise compile-time errors like "you cannot transition from a final state" or "the target state does not exists" etc...

Let's start with the state "type" definition.
A state node can be either of type "initial", "state" or "final".

So in my configuration, I'll keep a property with type the literal value of the type. (e.g. see EmptyStateConfig type).

In order to update the type, what I need to do at type level is override the type of the field, and substitute it with a new one.

calling `new State().type("final")` should return as type `State<{ type: "final" }>`.

Unfortunately, TS is yelling at me saying that the type of return of the type method is not valid because it does not satisfy the AnyStateConfig type as it is missing the untouched keys of the override (but they are there!).

Please check the following code to understand more:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
type Override<T, K extends keyof T, V> = Omit<T, K> & { [N in K]: V }

type AnyStateConfig = {
    type: "initial" | "state" | "final"
    states: {[K: string]: AnyStateConfig}
}

type EmptyStateConfig = {
    type: "state"
    states: {}
}


class State<C extends AnyStateConfig = EmptyStateConfig>{

    constructor(
        public readonly config: C
    ){

    }

    // the following line breaks.
    type<StateType extends AnyStateConfig["type"]>(type: StateType): State<Override<C, "type", StateType>>{
        return new State({ ...(this.config as any), type})
    }
}
```

Using TS 2.9 or 3.0 with strict: true

Comment: Please include your code in the question to preserve your questions long-term value.

Comment: Could you post your Exclude type as well?

Comment: Exclude is a built-in TS type as of 2.8 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is not smart enough to reason that if `C extends AnyStateConfig`, then `Exclude<keyof C, "type">` must include `"states"`.  Looks like there's [an existing issue report](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24791).  A workaround I found is to intersect `C` with `AnyStateConfig` again:

```
type<StateType extends AnyStateConfig["type"]>(type: StateType): State<Override<AnyStateConfig & C, "type", StateType>>{
    return new State({ ...(this.config as any), type})
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot accept the workaround as it will clean up previous props from the object. I will use instead @ts-ignore comment until bug is fixed in ts! Thanks anyway for pointing to the issue